# How to stop vs2012 express c++ editor changing std::vector<char> * to std::has_move_constructor<char> * in my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

How to stop vs2012 express c++ editor changing `std::vector<char> *` to `std::has_move_constructor<char> *` in my code?

Thank you a lot,

Best regards,
Kelvin gan

Comment: Add `#include <vector>` at the top of your cpp file.  I assume you mean intellisense is correcting it for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had added #include <vector>